# Symfony how to validate incoming image encoded in base64?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, base64, symfony-2.8

I recieve in POST request image encoded in base64. How I can validate that image? I tried to save it as temporary image in filesystem, but symfony constraints for images doesn't pass it like not uploaded one. Maybe I miss something or can create transformer or new constraints?

I'm using symfony 2.8.

Comment: >  I tried to save it as temporary image in filesystem.  How?
  > symfony constraints doesn't pass it like not uploaded one.  What is the output?

Comment: @AndyGauge if I'm not mistaken message is: "The file could not be uploaded.". How? With UploadedFile. I generate such one and put into request

Comment: you can write your custom validator checking that [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) return a valid response. Let me know you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement a custom [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) for the given form field. It should convert the data to and from base64.

Comment: Then you've implemented/used it wrong. If you correctly transform between a base64 string and <whatever the entity expects> (UploadedFile?), then validation should pass.

Comment: Validation makes call to [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file) and this file is not uploaded and we get validation error.

Comment: Try using File instead of UploadedFile